How can I specify a custom folder for storing output.xml, report.html, and log.html when running Robot Framework test cases from the interface?
Firstly by interface i mean clicking on the run play button displayed in the image.Run through run play button
When click on the button and it executes the test case but it stores the results output files in root.
I want the files to be stored on the specified location. How can i do that ?
It is working when i executes it from python runner.py file. It stores at specified location.
But my requirement is to run from the interface and store it at specified custom location.
And I need to control output directory by code not by any IDE or windows/Mac settings !
I've not got anything yet.

Create a file called robot.toml on the root of your project.
Edit the file and define the output folder like this: output-dir = "<OUTPUT_DIR>"
Example: output-dir = "tests/logs"
For more information: https://robotcode.io/02_get_started/configuration
